# How to use ios emoji repalce Android emoji when using canvas.drawText()

Tags: android, canvas, emoji, drawtext

android devices cannot show new ios9 Emoji. So,I want to use ios emoji replace android emoji.using [emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) can support TextView and EditText.

But,I have a custom View use canvas.drawText() to draw text.This will display android emoji.

How to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

```
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStrokeWidth(r);
    p.setColor(outerCircleColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, outerR, p);

    p.setColor(centerColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, r, p);

    p.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
    p.setColor(lineColor);
    canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, pointLine1Corner.x, pointLine1Corner.y, p);
    canvas.drawLine(pointLine1Corner.x, pointLine1Corner.y, pointLine1End.x, pointLine1End.y, p);

    p.setColor(textColor);
    p.setTextSize(defaultTextsize);
    canvas.drawText(displayText1, pointLine1Corner.x + defaultTextPadding, pointLine1Corner.y - defaultTextMarginBottom, p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `StaticLayout` to draw text for you instead of `canvas.drawText`, using `EmojiconHandler`'s `addEmojis` method to turn `SpannableString` into String with emojicon provided emoji icon. and pass the `SpannableString` to `StaticLayout` and call `draw` method to draw the text